# Purrring through

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm using fingertipsR to obtain public health data.

There are indicators at different geographic levels and these indicators are also grouped at profile level.

Here's some code:

```
library(fingertipsR)
library(fingertipscharts)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
fingertips_stats()


inds<-indicators_unique()
profs<-profiles()
```

it's possible to pull unique indicators for profiles like this and then to add a column  like this

```
smoking<-indicators_unique(ProfileID = 18,DomainID = NULL)%>%mutate(prof_id="18")
```

What I'd like to do is:

for each unique profile ID generate a dataframe of indicators. There are 53 unique profiles

```
uniqueprofs<-as_tibble(unique(profs$ProfileID))
```

How can I purr through this? or loop?

I am routinely stuck on these iteration type problems.

EDIT:
so. if you ctrl + click on 
`indicators_unique`
you'll see the bit: 
`df <- unique(df[, c("IndicatorID", "IndicatorName")])`

I copied all of the function and called it something else

```
function (ProfileID = NULL, DomainID = NULL, path) 
{
  if (missing(path)) 
    path <- fingertips_endpoint()
  #fingertips_ensure_api_available(endpoint = path)
  df <- indicators(ProfileID, DomainID, path = path)
  df <- unique(df[, c("IndicatorID", "IndicatorName","ProfileID")])
  return(df)
}
```

And I now get a dataframe containing the ProfileID. If I add "DomainID" I can have that too....

Edit:
Annoyingly, I've asked a similar question and updated it with dplyr `group_by` and `group_walk`

I can do this:

`inds%>%group_by(ProfileID)%>%group_walk(~ write.csv(.x, paste0(.y$ProfileID, ".csv")))`

How do I `group_walk` and write the dataframes/tibbles to the environment rather than writing them a drive and then loading them in?

Comment: When I run `inds<-fingertips_data()`, I get `Error in fingertips_data(): One of IndicatorID, DomainID or ProfileID must have an input`.

Comment: ah. that's an error. it shouldn't be there. edited line out.

Answer (score 1):

Start with some minimal initial code

```
library(fingertipsR)
library(tidyverse)
profs<-profiles()
```

`indictators_unique` is already vectorized so rather than loading the ProfileIDs into a tibble, put them in a list and then you can do a simple

```
unique_profs <- list(unique(profs$ProfileID))
indicators_unique(ProfileID = unique_profs, DomainID = NULL)
```

The issue is adding your desired `prof_id` column. I'm not familiar with these packages. Is there any dataframe that links `ProfileID` to either `IndicatorID` or `IndicatorName` that you can do a `join` on?

Comment: I'm going to add a comment in the original question as I think I've got something.